# Meaning of $v_\mathrm{source}$ in the Doppler effect

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, doppler-effect, signal-processing

The Doppler equation is given by 
$$f_{observed} = \frac{c+v_r}{c+v_s} \cdot{ f_{emitted}}$$

Does $v_s$ refer to the velocity of the source, relative to the receiver at the time the wave (now at the receiver) was released from the source? Or is $v_s$ the instantaneous velocity, relative to the receiver, at the time the wave is received by the receiver?

I'm guessing it's the former, but wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 3):

All velocities in this formula are relative to the medium in which the wave propagates. In the case of sound waves, this is usually velocity relative to the air. For sources and receivers moving with variable velocities, the velocity of the source is measured at the moment the wave was emitted and the velocity of the receiver is at the time the wave is received. This means that the frequency of the wave as measured by the receiver may vary in time if either of the two (source or receiver) has some acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is the former. I am tempted to say that the latter statement breaks a (postulate?) of special relativity 'no signal can travel faster than light', but this would be abuse of physics as the equation itself contradicts SR in the sense that it is Newtonian.

TL;DR this is true because waves at arbitrary points in a medium cannot be affected by the velocity of the source.

As the source moves towards the wave, the change in wavelength is observed at the source and is given by $$\lambda' = \lambda-{v_s}{t_0}$$ where $v_s$ is the velocity of the source relative to the medium. and $t_0$ is time period. This means that $c-v_s=f \lambda'$. The shifted wavelength $\lambda'$ is fixed once the observed cross section of the wave has left the source and stays the same at any receiver. But the velocity of the wave is affected by the velocity of the receiver (relative to the medium). It is clear that $c-v_r = \lambda'f'$. Hence both velocities have different effects on the wave. One changes the wavelength when it is released at the source, the other changes the frequency at the receiver.  We are left with

$$f' = f\frac{c-v_r}{c-v_s}$$

To remove ambiguity in 3d, replace $v$ with the dot product of $v$ and the unit vector of the wave direction. So when $v_r$ is directed toward the wave, we obtain $+v_r$ as required

One thing that seemed paradoxical to me while deriving this was the fact that the velocity of the receiver relative to the source does not have the same effect as an equal and opposite velocity of the source relative to the receiver. A phenomenon that seemingly breaks Newton's first law. This is resolved by considering that velocity of the medium can be different in either case, so the frames are not galilean shifts. The (non relativistic) doppler effect happens because of velocity relative to the *medium*, not relative to source.